# i am trying to make a user registration page. my code runs smoothly but my final frame and components aren't being dislayed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

im currently trying to make a registration page for my alevel computer science nea using java swing and Gui. my code so far seems to be correct with no errors but i cant seem to get the final window to display with all the components.
when i run my code on intellij it displays"Process finished with exit code 0" which means no error but my window and components aren't being dispalyed.
i have tried messing around with different things and though i hadn't set the frames visibility to true but all that has been done so i'm at a loss to what is wrong.
i have put in my code so if anyone has any idea what i'm missing and could help id really appreciate it

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainRegistrationPage {

    private JTextField Firstname;
    private JTextField Lastname;
    private JTextField Email;
    private JTextField Password;
    private JFrame Frame;
    private JButton Submit;



    public MainRegistrationPage() {

        //create user interface
        Frame= new JFrame("Registration Page");
        Frame.setSize(500,500);
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //add to frame
        //Frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel );
        Frame.setSize(400,300);
        Frame.setVisible(true);




        //create Jpanel to hold everythoing
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel.add(Firstname);
        mainPanel.add(Lastname);
        mainPanel.add(Email);
        mainPanel.add(Password);
        mainPanel.add(Submit);

        //create font
        Font greatFont = new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        Firstname = new JTextField(5);
        Firstname.setBounds(50,100,200,30);
        Firstname.setFont(greatFont);
        Firstname.setVisible(true);




        Font greatFont2 = new Font("Georgia",Font.PLAIN, 14);
        Lastname = new JTextField(5);
        Lastname.setBounds(50,150,200,30);
        Lastname.setFont(greatFont2);
        Lastname.setVisible(true);

        Font greatFont3 = new Font ("Georgia", Font.PLAIN,14);
        Email = new JTextField(5);
        Email.setBounds(50,200,200,30);
        Email.setFont(greatFont3);
        Email.setVisible(true);

        Font greatFont4 = new Font ("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        Password= new JTextField(5);
        Password.setBounds(50,250,200,30);
        Password.setFont(greatFont4);
        Password.setVisible(true);

//button
        JButton Submit = new JButton("Submit");
        Submit.setBounds(50,300,200,30);
        Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        //create labels
       // JLabel fJLabel = new JLabel("Firstname");
      // JLabel lJLabel = new JLabel("Lastname");
       // JLabel eJLabel = new JLabel("Email");
        //JLabel pJLabel = new JLabel("Password");


        //add to the frame
        Frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        Frame.setSize(300,350);
```

Comment: The main thing you're missing is a Swing layout for your `JPanel`.  I'd suggest the `GridBagLayout` since this is a form.  The other thing you're missing is methods.  Write separate methods for creating the `JFrame` and the `JPanel`.  Separate methods help you to organize your code and separate your concerns.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code into my IDE and it didn't compile.  After adding the two missing closing brackets and a static main method, I was greeted with a run time error.

After fixing the run time error, I finally got your GUI to display components.

Java variable names start with a lowercase letter.  This helps separate them visually from class names which start with an uppercase letter.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

I went ahead and fixed your code.  Here's the GUI.

[image: Registration]

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` and `JPanel`.  This allowed me to focus on one part of the GUI at a time and separate my concerns.

I used a `GridBagLayout` to create the registration form.  I created the Swing components in a left-to-right, top-to-bottom order to make the code easier for people to read and understand.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainRegistrationPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainRegistrationPage();
            }
        });
    }

    private JTextField firstname;
    private JTextField lastname;
    private JTextField email;
    private JPasswordField password;

    private JFrame frame;

    public MainRegistrationPage() {

        // create user interface
        frame = new JFrame("Registration Page");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createRegistrationPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createRegistrationPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 14);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("First Name:");
        label.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        firstname = new JTextField(30);
        firstname.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(firstname, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Last Name:");
        label.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        lastname = new JTextField(30);
        lastname.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(lastname, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Email:");
        label.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        email = new JTextField(30);
        email.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(email, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Password:");
        label.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        password = new JPasswordField(30);
        password.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(password, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(submit, gbc);

        return mainPanel;
    }

}
```